# Cannot render coffeescript partial inside coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rendering, coffeescript, partials

I want to make a general controller that can be called after the page was loaded (with AJAX) and update different stuff on the page depending on which controller called it.

The purpose is to allow better page and fragment caching, while displaying custom elements for the users.

My framework looks like this:

```
controllers/general_ajax_controller.rb
views/general_ajax/on_page_load.js.coffee
                 ./_update_some_stuff.js.coffee
```

The `on_page_load` action in the controller handles the logic of figuring out which partials to load and the view will render the partials.

In the `on_page_load.js.coffee` view I have this code (simplified):

```
<%= render "update_some_stuff" %>
```

which should render the partial. Instead I get this error:

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: Reserved word "function" on line 2):
  app/views/general_ajax/on_page_load.js.coffee:1:in `_app_views_general_ajax_on_page_load_js_coffee___2304196970850216490_70321203283120'
```

I think that the coffeescript is compiled before including it in the view (which is coffee and does not support compiled js)

If I change the extension of the `on_page_load` view to `.js.erb` then **it works**.
(Oddly enough, I have to restart my server before it works, do you know why?)

**Do you think this is an issue in coffeescript or is it bad practice and therefore not supported?**

As a side discussion, what do you think of my approach to dynamic scrips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `_update_some_stuff.js.coffee` is interpreted and converted to Javascript. When it is inserted into `on_page_load.js.coffee` it raises an error because vanilla Javascript code is not compatible inside a Coffee-Script file (the `function` keyword in this case).

Comment: Yes I agree, this is what's causing the problem. But what do you recommend instead of `render "update_some_stuff"`? How to properly use coffeeScript partials?

Comment: I don't know. I have not needed this yet. I have used respond_to to render javascript. Maybe from there you can just render one file or another based on some condition, and using Rails partials.

Comment: My idea was to separate the files so each has its own functionality and that it's possible to load them individually, depending if they're needed or not (some sort of lazy load). Sometimes it's needed to load more files at once, so a render call wouldn't work here.

Comment: I have been sometimes in similar situations, and I felt stalled, just like you. I think that if that is not possible to do, it must be because it is not the way to do it. Stop and think about another way to accomplish what you need. Take into account that every Rails request can be responded with javascript, and that javascript is automatically executed.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to embed a raw parsed javascript into the view.

Notice the back ticks (which tell coffeescript this is raw javascript) and use of raw() to undo HTML escaping of the rendered partial.

```rb
`
<%= raw(render("update_some_stuff")) %>
`
```